# Why do I get "No url found for submodule path 'spongehunters' in .gitmodules"?

Tags: git, github, build-error

[GitHub Build Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpdNl.jpg)

"**build**

No url found for submodule path 'spongehunters' in .gitmodules

**build**

The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128

**build**

The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128"

How do I resolve this issue? I am trying to update a website utilizing R Studio and it recently started giving me this error out of no where when I try to push through GitHub.

Comment: I don't know that this has anything to do with [tag:r] or [tag:rstudio], it seems more of a git/github/github-actions thing.

Answer (score 0):

In the folder spongehunters, there's probably a `.git` folder. So this means that there are two .git folders. One under the main repo and another one in the spongehunters folder.

Delete the one in the spongehunters folder.